# JAVAFX: Responsive Tab

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating new tabs dynamically loading an FXML file for each tab.

```
Tab newOrderTab = new Tab();
orderTabPane.getTabs().add(newOrderTab);
newOrderTab.setContent((Node) FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("/fxml/OrderTabScene/OrderTabScene.fxml")));
```

My problem is that the new tab content is not responsive and does not fill with the TabPane.

Remembering that I can't set AnchorPane bottomAnchor, leftAnchor... because the tab has its own FXML file and the parent its the TabPane that it's on the main FXML file.

[image: problem_image]

TabPane FXML file:

```
 <TabPane fx:id="orderTabPane" layoutY="66.0" prefHeight="303.0" prefWidth="640.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="2.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="66.0">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Pedido 1">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
```

Tab FXML file:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="570.0" />
            <TableView layoutX="233.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="305.0" prefWidth="353.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="146.0" text="Item" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="51.0" text="Qty" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="77.0" text="Price" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="78.0" text="Total" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

How can I fill Tab content to the TabPane size?

Obs.: TabPane it's inside a VBox (main object) and its sizes change with the VBox.

Comment: Well, you can get the `AnchorPane` of the content via `FXMLLoader.load`—just cast the returned `Node`. However, a better option is to use a better layout for the `Tab`'s content; one that resizes/re-positions its children when its dimensions change. `AnchorPane` is really only good for static layouts and even then it might not look the same on all displays.

Comment: `Pane` is inherently unresponsive. I recommend using a `VBox` instead and setting `VBox.vgrow` to `ALWAYS` for the `TableView`...